# Using startsWith and paste0 together

Tags: r, paste, startswith

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
Frequency  Period No.  Period
Q1         3
Q2         6
Q3         9
```

If the value in the Frequency column starts with "Q", I want the Period column to be filled with the respective Quarter (i.e. if Frequency is Q1, the Period is Q1). I DO NOT want this to be done by simply pasting the values in the Frequency column to the Period column.

I'm currently trying to use startsWith and paste0 to do this:

```
df$Frequency[startsWith(df$Frequency, "Q")] <- paste0("Q", (df$`Period No.`)-1)%/%3+1)
```

I'm getting the error

```
Error in startsWith(df$Frequency, "Q") : 
  non-character object(s)
```

Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: most likely df$Frequency is a factor. Check with class(df$Frequency). Then do df$Frequency = as.character(df$Frequency) ; then do the substitution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `case_when` or `ifelse` or simple assignment with index

```
i1 <- grepl("^Q\\d+", df$Frequency)
df$Period[i1] <- df$`Period No.`[i1]
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your data frame characters are parsed as factor, which means they are hidden integers.

to avoid that, you can either put the option stringsAsFactors=FALSE when you read or construct the data.frame... Or update to version 4.0 which has just removed this default behavior ;)

Then, you're likely to get another problem cause you have to subset the right side df$`Period No.` in order to have the same amount of obs than in the left side.

example of resolution, reparsing the factor as characters :

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("john","jane","pamela","jessica"),b=1:4)
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
boolean <- startsWith(df$a,"j")
df[boolean,"a"] <- df[boolean,"b"]
```